# VS 32-bit debugging instead of 64-bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, x86-64

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.6.  Starting yesterday, debugging in Chrome gets me this error:

> The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps.

Fair enough, I go up to the Debug dropdowns to pick x64, and all they have is Any CPU.  Going into the Debug configuration manager, this is the only option I have as well, whether editing or creating a new profile.

How do I get the x86 and x64 bit options back?
Debugging in Edge works, but I don't want to use Edge.

Comment: It is a known problem.  Always look for VS2017 agile bugs by searching https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com first, type msvsmon in the search box.  Get in touch with the Microsoft employee that works on the debugger to provide him the info he needs.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and checked that forum.  I can get debugging to work by following the procedure of the last post, which is to go to Tools|Options|Debugging|General and unchecking the "Enable Javascript debugging in Chome and IE", but this does not bring back the target bitness options.

Comment: From what Hans said, you'll need to install a 64-bit version of the debugger to debug 64-bit target processes.  His point was that this limitation is already known, not that there's a fix.  Just workarounds for some cases like you found.

Comment: You could always use a different debugger, outside of VS.  There are some pretty good assembly-level debuggers, if that helps.

Comment: @Darryl, Do you really debug an app locally or remotely? If just debug app locally, it just has the Any CPU platform in default, but I think you could add the x84/X64 in your side: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms. But if you debug remotely, it really has the limitation as Peter's suggestion even if you could change/add the platform.

Comment: @Fletch, I am trying to debug locally.  I followed your link and tried various ways in the build config manager and debug manager to find an option for a 64bit target build, but all i have is Any CPU.  Adding a new configuration doesnt add a 64 bit option.  Peter, a couple days ago, VS 2017 was debugging in Chrome just fine, so i shouldnt have to download or use a different debugger.  I think I updated VC with a new build and broke this functionality.

Comment: @Darryl, Actually I could debug a simple web app using the VS2017 with the Chrome browser(with Any CPU), I use the latest VS2017 as yours in windows, just to make this issue clearly, whether other browser like IE also has this issue? Which Chrome version did you use? I just use the default VS settings, if possible, just reset your VS settings, and then create a new web project, debug it again.

Comment: @Darryl, Any update for this issue? If you get any latest information, please feel free to let me know.